# Laravel outputs only debug and info logs

Tags: php, laravel, logging

For some reason, on the production environment, when I run into an error, I don't see that in my `laravel.log` file.

when I do this:

```
Log::critical('test', []);
```

It does output a critical error log.

But when I do something like this:

```
Log::critical('test', TRYING TO MAKE AN EXTERNAL ERROR);
```

I don't get an error in my `laravel.log` file, which should output this error:

```
PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ')' on line 1
```

I have these lines in my .env file:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:....
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=....
```

According to Laravel's docs, when I type "debug" on my Log level, the logger should at least log: `debug, info, notice, warning, error, critical, alert, emergency`.

the `storage` folder marked as a 775 permission.

Am I missing something here? I've already tried to delete the `laravel.log` file and it didn't help.

---

**Update**

I've tried to edit the php.ini and the error log was `On` and I have specified the error log location and it still didn't work. It looks like it's beyond Laravel issue.